# YII (PHP Framework) and OSX (El Capitan)

Tags: php, apache, yii, osx-elcapitan

After I upgraded the Mac OSX my development environment stopped working.  I am not sure if it is something related with the apache provided by apple, but what is happening is that when I try to access the application it complains that some of the required files are not found.

I have the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^install\/ ./index.php?r=install/main/index [L,QSA]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php

addDefaultCharset utf-8 code here
```

At the httpd.conf I enabled php and rewrite modules. I've also set the AllowOverride to All in the Directory sector in the httpd.conf.

These are the error I am getting when trying to access:

[image: The last error occurred because the js wasn't loaded]

Also, when I try to access any other url that is mapped on the yii, I get the same error 404 Not Found.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance and regards,
Edu

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have mod_rewrite enabled in the Apache settings.

Make sure this line is not commented out in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: Thanks fire, but this was the first steps to along with the php module.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just noticed that I set the AllowOverride All int the wrong place.  I just set it in the Directory of the right host and it worked.

Thanks and regards.